# Can a grappling creature cause a prone creature it is grappling to be unprone?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, forced-movement, prone

If my character is grappling a creature who has been knocked prone, that creature can't stand back up unless they succeed in first breaking free of the grapple.

Do the [rules for moving a grappled creature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) allow my character to cause the grappled & prone creature to stand up and stop being prone?

> **Moving a Grappled Creature**. When you move, you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

Comment: I feel like this might be an XY problem. Why are you trying to unprone the creature?

Comment: Related: "[Can you help a prone character to stand up?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108997)" and "[If a prone creature is grappled and moved by a flying enemy, does the creature stay prone?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152317)" and "[Can I force a creature out of prone during a grapple?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167564)"

Comment: I affirm the allegations of duplicature,  but do not want to dupe hammer it.

Comment: Not sure why my question search didn't turn that dupe up. Maybe I used a problematic match term like "unprone" or something. At any rate, thanks Medix!

Comment: @Thom Aside from me, the tank, our party ended up with a Kobold cleric who won't care about/benefit from the prone condition. Only I would benefit (in that it's harder to hit me and increases my survivablity). But we also have a ranged caster and Arcane Archer Fighter for whom the prone status would become a *bad* thing to shoot at. So I want to use prone on creatures I'm tanking until it comes time to kill them and then set them on their feet for the ranged characters to shoot at.

Comment: Won't they just drop prone again, rather than get shot?

Comment: @Mark I was imagining hauling the grappled creature to its feet and holding it up.

Comment: Under the rules, though, they can drop prone any time, and if you're doing this then I assume you're way off in the weeds of rules-over-everything gameplay.

Comment: @Mark True enough. We haven't discussed how we'd handle this at the table but, foreseeing it as a possibility in the future, I thought I'd check in advance to help guide table adjudication. I *do*, however, wonder if the grappled creature truly can voluntarily drop to prone when grappled. The rules seem to suggest that being physically on the ground is a requirement. I'd ask about this as a separate question but I fear it would just be pedantic and ultimately boil down to "DM decides."

Comment: @Rykara Ready action to haul the creature back to its feat after its turn ends.